# CAML Query for Week and Month not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I following CAML Query does not work:

```
<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Week /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>
```

**AND**

```
<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month/></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>
```

But this one works:

```
<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Yearly /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>
```

The only difference is that the working query has `<Yearly />` as Date time and the non working queries have `<Week />` and `<Month />`.

This is a big issue for me as it has a big performance impact.  Can someone provide some guidance as to what muight be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateRangesOverlap has many issues, the one you are facing might be explained here: [Issue](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2008/03/04/using-month-element-in-daterangesoverlap-can-return-items-not-in-the-specified-month/). The same author has provided a solution [Solution](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/how-to-find-overlapping-items-for-a-date-range/)

Comment: Yeh, it does have lots of bugs... :(