# cannot retrieve complete dates of single reccuring calendar event in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am using share point custom web part, i want to retrieve all the dates of single recurring calendar event.

For example i have created a calendar recurring monthly event that will last from December 2013 to December 2016

i am able to retrieve dates for one year only, that is  from December 2013 to December 2014 only and not able to retrieve other dates using  Collaborative Application Markup Language query

Comment: I used below query but not working,

query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Eq><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Year /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></And></Where>";

Comment: You probably want to search on stackoverflow or Google. You'll get, for example, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704978/caml-query-for-week-and-month-not-working